# Look up a value in an Array using Dynamic Rows and columns

Tags: excel, vba, match, indexof

So I need to be able to find a value in an array by first using the first row, then the second row and lastly using the column.  All variables are defined dynamically because this lookup function is going to be running through a for loop. I have tried to use an Index-Match function with no success so far, I cant share the file and code I am currently working on because of security reasons but I made a sample sheet that replicates it.

[image: Image of array posted here]  Please any help on the best way to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your data sample, the row can be found just by looking at the value in column B, because it is unique. But for the sake of the exercise, let's pretend it is not unique and B can have duplicates.

If you want to return the match for 2-6 in column 2000, then you can use this Index/Match formula.

```
=INDEX($C$3:$H$10,MATCH(2&6,INDEX($A$3:$A$10&$B$3:$B$10,0),0),MATCH(2000,$C$2:$H$2,0))
```

Or, use cell references for the dynamic parameters, as in the screenshot.

```
=INDEX($C$3:$H$10,MATCH(A12&B12,INDEX($A$3:$A$10&$B$3:$B$10,0),0),MATCH(C12,$C$2:$H$2,0))
```

[image]

You don't want to use whole column references for this approach, since the inner Index of the first Match combines the values of two columns. If you want your spreadsheet to perform above crawl speed, use ranges with defined rows and colums.

Comment: If that takes care of your problem, please mark the answer as described in the [tour].

Comment: I am trying to code this into VBA,  Using the the 2 rows and columns to find the cell value I need.  Say I need to find the value that corresponds in row1= 2, row2=7 and column=5000,  I want the VBA code to output "89" if that makes sense

Comment: But the code uses dynamic variable for each column row1 = A, row2=B and column1= C

Comment: You can use the formula in VBA. That might be easier than reinventing an Index/Match in VBA. Use `Application.WorksheetFunction' and construct a string with your VBA variables.